# Change the content type in the request headers

Tags: json, node.js, body-parser

I am supposed to send data from an app to the server and the post method from that app is made using content type as `application/json` but it is plain text. I cannot update the app to change this header now. The current app is working as the data reaches PHP directly and PHP doesn't parse the incoming data which is specified as json.

```
import express from 'express'
var http = require('http')
const redirectionRoutes = express.Router()

redirectionRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.rawBody = ''
  req.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain'

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    req.rawBody += chunk
  })

  req.on('end', function() {
    next()
  })
})

redirectionRoutes.post(/^\/update_services\/.*$/, function(request, response) {
    var data = request.rawBody
    var dataLength = data.length
    var options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: request.path,
        method: 'POST',
        json: false,
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': dataLength
        }
    }

    var buffer = ''
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', function() {
        response.send(buffer)
        })
    })
    req.write(data)
    req.end()
})
```

But in nodejs(my application), as the content type is specified as json, the body parser is parsing the data and as it's not json, I am getting an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at createStrictSyntaxError (../node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
at parse (../node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
at /Users/../node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/Users/../node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
at done (/Users/../node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/../node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
```

Is there a way in nodejs/body parser to not to parse this incoming json and let is get into the function as plain text.

Comment: can you show us the code where there is `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: I do not have JSON.parse anywhere, I even removed bodyParser @user1851595

Answer (score 0):

It is solved!!
I am exporting this module at the end of the app code along with other pages routers. So, the body-parser being called in previous libraries are being called if I didn't use in this particular router.